# Google Earth API getting camera's absolute position

Tags: c#, google-earth

For a project at school I need to have to absolute position of the camera.

I setup the camera with an tilt of 90 degrees so that it looks like a 1st person view, then I need to calculate the distance between the camera and between another point.

But when I use the google earth API, the camera latitude and longitude are from the focuspoint and not from the absolute camera position.

Is there another way to read out these parameters or should I calculate backwards with the Range and Tilt?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Earth API defines two methods for getting the current camera view: `copyAsLookAt()` and `copyAsCamera()`. I think the latter is what you need. More information at the [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/earth/documentation/camera_control.html).

Next time, please double check the documentation before asking here!